# Error pjsua on windows

Tags: python, sip, pjsip

I want to start programming my SIP client and I started with an example of pjsua to test [REGISTRATION CODE](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/browser/pjproject/trunk/pjsip-apps/src/python/samples/registration.py?rev=2171)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\work\zscenter\registration.py", line 49, in <module>
 lib.create_transport(pj.TransportType.UDP, pj.TransportConfig(5080))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pjsua.py", line 2301, in create_transport
err, tp_id = _pjsua.transport_create(type, cfg._cvt_to_pjsua())
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pjsua.py", line 536, in _cvt_to_pjsua
cfg.qos_type = self.qos_type
AttributeError: '_pjsua.Transport_Config' object has no attribute 'qos_type'
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'" 
in     <bound method Lib.__del__ of <pjsua.Lib instance at 0x0212AE40>> ignored
```

can someone help me please ?

Comment: Could you please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I installed the latest version and its working fine thanks